# Has the response from FB.ui requests changed?

Tags: facebook, fb.ui

It used to be that the response from a request gave us an array of request ids (as described here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) but it seems now the response variable returns two items insead 'to' and 'request'. To being a comma delimited string of user ids and request being a request id. Is this correct? I have seen nothing about this anywhere but it is the behavior I am seeing currently.

**Update**
Here is a super simplified version of my call:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'My Great Request'}, requestCallback);
function requestCallback(response) {
    for(var key in response){
        console.log(key);
        console.log(response[key]);
    }
}
```

When I make a request to one person the variable response has two keys: request and to. Request is a request id, to is the id of the person I'm sending the request to. If I make a call to the graph api using the provided request id, however, I find that the user under both 'to' and 'from' are equal to the sender's name and fbid.

Alternatively, if I request to multiple people request is equal to a single request id and to is an array containing all the fbids of the users that had requests sent to them. When I make a call to the graph api, however, I once more find that both 'to' and 'from' contain the user id and name of the requesting user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar issue yesterday. Had to fix my code. But today request_ids were back in the response. So I updated the code again. But this time to work with both type of objects.

I found the documentation here (move down to the "Performance improvements" section)
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/569/

But it still doesn't explains why they reverted the change today. Or was it accidently released yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

As in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), the new callback will receive an `object` (`response`) that contains an `array` (`request_ids`) of request ids:

```
{
  "request_ids": [
    0: [request_id]
    1: [request_id]
    ...
  ]
}
```

So I suppose you can loop using this modified code:

```
function requestCallback(response) {
    for( var k in response.request_ids ) {
        console.log(k);
        console.log(response.request_ids[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read my question again, I'm saying that the behavior you have described is what I expected, it is not what I'm seeing.

Comment: It's not happening to me! Maybe the bug posted in the other answer would help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a bug filed here
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/129565473812085

There is no clear information yet whether the response is really changed or its a bug.